# delete lines before and after a string is found using sed

Tags: awk, sed

below is my xml file content -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<artifactListing>
    <folder id="REPORTMART" path="/Repository Objects" pathAlias="/00"
        modifiedBy="Maria" lastUpdated="1480426973000" description="Hyperion Root Folder"/>
    <folder id="DATASOURCESFOLD"
        path="/Repository Objects/HRInternalFolder/DataSources"
        pathAlias="/00/HRInternal/DataSources" modifiedBy="Maria" lastUpdated="1492814854000"/>
    <folder id="HRINTERNALFOLD"
        path="/Repository Objects/HRInternalFolder"
        pathAlias="/00/HRInternal" modifiedBy="Maria" lastUpdated="1492814854000"/>
    <folder id="00000158e031595b-0000-0782-0ae57730"
        path="/Repository Objects/TRCS" pathAlias="/00/0"
        modifiedBy="demoadmin" lastUpdated="1492814854000" description="TRCS"/>
    <resource id="JavaScriptUpdateResizeOn_dds_js"
        path="/Repository Objects/Administration/Impact Manager/Script Repository"
        pathAlias="/00/Administration/0/Script_Repository"
        modifiedBy="Maria" lastUpdated="1492814880000"
        description="JavaScript Update DDS configuration with Layout Manager"
        name="JavaScriptUpdateResizeOn_dds.js" type="text/im-javascript" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="449cb46e6b4492f3afb8ef693dffb43a90cdd992"
        path="/Security" pathAlias="/02"
        description="Shared Services Administrator"
        name="epm_default_cloud_admin" type="UserPreferences" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="0f62187cf5a8f5aecec7a9879c9e40497d6d8649"
        path="/Security" pathAlias="/02" description="" name="Jacob"
        type="UserPreferences" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="0df02da8548eeef2174c97c2ade67b4c5adc3160"
        path="/Security" pathAlias="/02" description="" name="Henry"
        type="UserPreferences" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="33dca1c0c1c5ae78f67580a76d9c6aba6a172e20"
        path="/Security" pathAlias="/02" description="" name="Susan"
        type="UserPreferences" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="3e182b1ea9376483a38614d916a0b666ef531b6d"
        path="/Security" pathAlias="/02" description="" name="Maria"
        type="UserPreferences" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="0f62187cf5a8f5aecec7a9879c9e40497d6d8649"
        path="/Security" pathAlias="/02" description="" name="Jacques"
        type="UserPreferences" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="0df02da8548eeef2174c97c2ade67b4c5adc3160"
        path="/Security" pathAlias="/02" description="" name="Frank"
        type="UserPreferences" size="-1"/>
    <resource id="PP_3e182b1ea9376483a38614d916a0b666ef531b6d_0"
        path="/Product Preferences" pathAlias="/05"
        description="This is your default Personal Page."
        name="My Personal Page" type="PersonalPageContent" size="-1"/>
</artifactListing>
```

now using sed I would like to delete entire resource tag if "Susan" string is found within it, other non-Susan resource tag's should not be considered.
In this scenario, it's only 1 line before and after string, I've other cases where there are more line within the resource tag.

Comment: do you have the ability to use xml parsers?

Comment: to make it more clear, even before Susan resource tag there are other users resource tag, sorry if I missed that before.

Comment: Yes I can use xml parser.
tried with xmllint, but couldn't achieve what I wanted.

Comment: install xmlstarlet and I'll show how to do it

Comment: OK I have no root, will get it done and update you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XML parser is the right way for manipulating XML documents.

[***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//resource[@name="Susan"]' yourxmlfile
```

---

- `ed` - edit mode
- `-d` - delete action
- `//resource[@name="Susan"]` - xpath expression

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, try this:

```
$ sed -ibak -r '/^\s*<resource/!bend;:loop;N;/\/>.*$/{/Susan/d;bend};bloop;:end' filename
```

Explains:

1. `/^\s*<resource/!bend`: if `pattern space` does NOT start with `^\s*<resource`, jump to the label named `end` to start a new loop.
2. `:loop`: set a label named `loop` to deal with the whole `resource` tag.
3. `N`: use `N` command to append a `\n` and `next line` into `pattern space`.
4. `/\/>.*$/{/Susan/d}`: if current `pattern space` ends with `/>$`, which means we have got a complete `resource` tag in `pattern space`, then we can deal with it; if this complete `resource` tag contains `Susan`, which is your `pattern`, use `d` command to delete all contents in `pattern space` and then jump to label named `end` to start a new loop.
5. `bloop`: use a loop to append the remaining lines of current `resource` tag into `pattern space`.
6. use `-ibak` to backup the origin file.

P.S: It will ALSO work for other cases where there are more lines within the resource tag.

Comment: Thanks Weike.
When I run this, sed enters into infinite loop and when I interrupt I still see the file contents being same as before.

Comment: I see, that because your xml file contains more tags other than `resource`. Just wait a minute... i can fix it.

Comment: Also note there are more resource tags for other users even before Susan appears in the file.

Comment: can you paste the whole xml file?